# How do I make other columns change color based off another cells formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My Trading Journal

[image]

The range I want to modify

[image]

I have created a Forex Trading Journal that I need help on. In the ratio column G, I have a formula where It divides the take profit by the stop loss. This formula gives me the Risk: Reward ratio.

I would like it so that if the ratio is 3 - the Take Profit and Stop Loss Columns (E:F) will change green to signify this trade is following my plan. If it falls below or above, I'd also like to be able to change colors to visually show if the trade I am entering is following my plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional formatting:

#### Sample output:

[image: output]

These are the formula:

- If G is equal to 3, set to green

  - `=$G2=3`
- If G is less than 3 and not blank, set to red

  - `=AND($G2<3,$G2<>"")`
- If G is greater than 3, set to yellow

  - `=$G1>3`

#### Change color:

[image: color]

#### Note:

- We are checking `not blank` on 2nd formula since blank cells are treated as less than 3 and we need to exclude that.
- You can always change the color to be used. I just used my preference in my sample.
- To change color, click the fill button under `Formatting style`
- Take note of the range where the conditional formatting is applied. Yours should look like the one in my sample, `E2:G1000`.
- Read the references below to guide you

#### Reference:

- [Conditional Formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)
- [How to use Conditional Formatting](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/conditional-formatting-entire-row/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! The information you provided has helped tremendously. The spreadsheet is already starting to look better! Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @BHTrading, thanks for the confirmation. If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer